# Где обрабатывать исключения в приложении asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, исключения, asp.net-core

Где необходимо отлавливать исключения в приложении asp.net mvc? Например у меня есть функция в сервисе, которая использует базу данных:

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetAcount(string id)
{
    return await _applicationUserRepository.GetOrDefaultAsync(id);
}
```

Если будет ошибка подключения к базе данных будет исключение. Его можно <s>обработать</s> обойти в репозитории, например так:

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetOrDefaultAsync(string key)
{
    TEntity result = null;

    try
    {
        return await _entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == key);
    }
    catch { }

    return result;
}
```

Или в сервисе, например так:

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetAcount(string id)
{
    ApplicationUser result = null;
    try
    {
        result = await _applicationUserRepository.GetOrDefaultAsync(id);
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return result;
}
```

Или в контроллере, например так:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    ApplicationUser applicationUser = null;
    try
    {
        applicationUser = await _usersService.GetAcount(id);
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error");
    }
    if(applicationUser == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(applicationUser);
}
```

Можно вообще не отлавливать исключение, тогда при ошибке пользователь увидит это:
[image: Ошибка при исключении]

Где и как нужно обрабатывать исключения при работе с базой данных и нужно ли вообще их обрабатывать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исключения надо обрабатывать там, где их может обработать прикладная логика.

- Обрабатывать в репозитории - не рекомендуется, никакой код не сможет
  узнать, почему он не получил сущность.
- Обрабатывать в сервисе - уже вполне можно, возможно сервис должен
  создавать новую сущность, если не найдена нужная - это уже ваша
  логика и вам решать, как себя вести.
- В контроллере обработка тоже вполне допустима. Только вам самому надо
  решить, что это исключение значит и как на него реагировать.
  Контроллер - это уже выход на пользователя. Т.е. лучше предоставить
  пользователю информацию - что случилось, кто виноват и что с этим
  можно сделать. Просто "Ошибка" обычно абсолютно бесполезна.